# How do I make it so two adjacent divs take up remaining space without pushing/squeezing the main div?

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I have this layout:
[image]

This is the code for the image below:

```
<main>
      <div className="flex justify-center max-w-xl mx-auto bg-purple-400">
      ...
      </div>
</main>
```

What I want is to have two divs, one of the left and one on the right of this layout (in the white area) that take up the remaining space without affecting the width of the main content area. How can this be done?

I've experimented with this code, but I haven't figured it out yet:

```
<main className="flex">
      <div className="">left white area</div>
      <div className="flex justify-center max-w-xl mx-auto bg-purple-400">
      ...
      </div>
      <div className="">right white area</div>
</main>
```

UPDATE:

I was able to get the desired behaviour with media queries, even though I wanted to do this with native tailwind, this works as well:

```
--HTML--
<main className="flex">
      <div id="left" className="hidden">left white area</div>
      <div className="flex justify-center max-w-xl mx-auto bg-purple-400">
      ...
      </div>
      <div id="right" className="hidden">right white area</div>
</main>

--CSS--
@media screen and (min-width: 64rem) {
  #left,
  #right {
    width: calc((100vw - 64rem) / 2);
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I'll leave this thread open for any possible other solutions. If it can be figured out with just tailwind that's even better.

Edited again to clean up the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `flex-1` or `flex-grow` in the middle one, and instead of media queries for the side ones try `hidden md:block` and possibly something like `w-1/5`